# Snowflake: How can I find out which internal table stages consumes most storage?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my snowflake account I can see that there is a lot of storage used by stages. I can see this for example using the following query:

```
select *
from table(information_schema.stage_storage_usage_history(dateadd('days',-10,current_date()),current_date()));
```

There are no named stages in the databases. All used storage must be in internal stages.
How can I find out which internal stages consumes most storage?

If I know the name of the table I can list all files in the table stage using something like this:

```
list @SCHEMANAME.%TABLENAME;
```

My problem is that there are hundreds of tables in the databases and I have no idea which tables to query.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `ACCOUNT_USAGE` view called `STAGE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY` in the Snowflake database/share that will give you everything, including internal stages.  I would use this over the `information_schema` view, since that is limited to what your role currently has access to.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/stage_storage_usage_history.html

Comment: This view only shows me the total storage used for all stages in the account. I am looking for some way to find out which internal table stage is causing this storage use. STAGE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY only tells me that I have 500 GB data in stages, but it does not tell me where the data is so I can delete it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I misunderstood your question.  I don't see a view that has that detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view STAGES in Information schema or account usage to get the stages. Do note that Account usage has higher retention period than information schema and data retrieval is faster. You can read more [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/stages.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly,you want to do something with stages to reduce the overall billing or storage size

Snowflake Stages

1. 'Internal Named' and 'External' stages  : 
     These are the only stages which can be altered or dropped and controlled by user
2. User Stage and Table stages are one which can not be altered or dropped, 
     managed by snowflake

So even if you could identify those Table and User specific stages , you can not drop those.

Snowflake Storage consumption includes below three components for billing

```
   1. Databases size
   2. Stages size
   3. Fail Safe size
```

The size of the storage occupied can be visible (Only when you have Accountadmin role 
or MONITOR privs) under below location webUI tab

```
Account Tab ---> Usage --> Average Storage Used
```

Note : on the account tab, No DB object wise storage billing details available

So how you can see the storage consumption of the associated tables (including their fail safe and time travel bit) and stage details

```
 select * from <DB Name>."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS"
 select * from <DB Name>."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."STAGES"
```

Hope clarification helped

Thanks

Palash Chatterjee

Comment: I know that I have data in stages that I am getting billed for. It is visible in the web interface and in the view ACCOUNT_USAGE.STAGE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY. My problem is that I am unable to find what internal table stage or default user stage contains all this data. I am not interested in dropping the actual stages, I want to REMOVE the unnecessary large files that someone has uploaded.To do this I need to find where the files are. Also, the view TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS does not seem to include data stored in table stages.